# How to get xml node value based on attribute value c# , asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlnode

how to get xmlnode value based on attribute value in C#.

```
<Products>
  <Error>0</Error>
  <Product link="OWN">
    <ProductCode>CA</ProductCode>
    <ProductType>Account</ProductType>
    <ProductSubtype>Current Account</ProductSubtype>
    <ProductDescriptionEng>Current Account</ProductDescriptionEng>  
    <ProductNumber>1234567</ProductNumber>
    <ProductCurrency></ProductCurrency>
    <ProductCurrencyCode>01</ProductCurrencyCode>
    <ProductBalance>899293.003</ProductBalance>
    <LoanRef></LoanRef>
    <OldLoanRef></OldLoanRef>
    <ProductStandardID>00010001</ProductStandardID>
    <OldLoanRef></OldLoanRef>  
    <ProductStatusCode>00</ProductStatusCode>
    <ProductStatus>OPEN</ProductStatus>
    <ProductCategory>Deposit Account</ProductCategory>   
  </Product>
</Product>
```

in the above example i would like to get value of Product Link "OWN" based on passing attribute value (1234567)  1234567.

I have tried following code but it doesn't return value "OWN" from 'Product link" node.

```
string _accountsXml = GetProducts();
                _xmlDoc.LoadXml(_accountsXml);
                _productLinkType = _xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Products[../ProductNumber = '{0}']", prodNumber));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
_productLinkType = _xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Products[..//ProductNumber = '{0}']", prodNumber));
```

or

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(_accountsXml);
var productLinkType = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(string.Format("//Products[..//ProductNumber = '{0}']", prodNumber)).Element("Product").Attribute("link").Value;
```

The closing tag in your example is Product it should be Products

Comment: Thanks Pinaki.  The second option "Or" code works. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You do have to add code to get element's attribute value there, possibly minding the case when the right element was not found. Plus be careful with the element names - both in the xpath expression and in the XML.

The following test code would have "OWN" in the link variable:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>  
<Products>
    <Error>0</Error>
    <Product link=""Global""/>
    <Product link=""OWN"">
        <Some/>
        <ProductNumber>1234567</ProductNumber>
        <Nodes/>
    </Product>
    <Product link=""External"">
        <ProductNumber>777</ProductNumber>
    </Product>
</Products>");

var id = 1234567;
var link = doc
    .XPathSelectElement($"//Product[ProductNumber = '{id}']")
    ?.Attribute("link")
    ?.Value;

Console.WriteLine($"Product link: {link ?? "not found"}");
```

Comment: Thanks DK.  Perfect. It works. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks Pinaki. Appreciate. :)